# php mysql insert statement using variables

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

my php code which is throwing errors is as follows:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare('INSERT INTO listOfRides (address, time) VALUES 
('$address', '$time')') ;
```

I have looked at other posts and it seems I am using the variables correctly with the single quotes around them however the following error is being shown when visiting the URL:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/gbidjght/public_html
/insertRide.php on line 79
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Why not use placeholders and ->execute() for the values?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-insert-statement

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you escaped the single quotes you would end up with the string literals "$address" and "$time" being inserted into your DB:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare('INSERT INTO listOfRides (address, time) VALUES (\'$address\', \'$time\')');
```

However assuming that they should be variables, you should use double quotes around your SQL statement to allow PHP to actually parse your variables as their values:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO listOfRides (address, time) VALUES ('$address', '$time')");
```

That being said, since you're already preparing your statement, why not just use placeholders anyway? It'll be a safer way to protect against SQL injection.

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO listOfRides (address, time) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->execute(array($address, $time));
```

Comment: Tit for tat? Thanks @Fred-ii-

Comment: Well, sort of *wink*. However as truth may be and being a latest topic of discussion on meta, is the quality of answers *lately*. I'm not sure if you've seen it, but it's been a bit hot these passed few days. It's about these *"Try this...."* with drop-in code type of answers. I'm not fancy on that, as are many members on Stack who frequently help and provide answers/solutions. I've fallen victim to refused flags as VLQ, and not a happy camper. How will anyone learn how to feed themselves, if we don't show them "how to" fish. ;-) *Cheers*

Answer (score 4):

change the outer quotes to double quotes

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO listOfRides (address, time) VALUES 
('$address', '$time')") ;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't put mysql `'` in php `'`

Use this

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO listOfRides (address, time) VALUES 
('$address', '$time')") ;
```

Answer (score 2):

Because of the `'`s the error is coming. Add `"` instead of `'`.Try this -

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO listOfRides (address, time) VALUES ('$address', '$time')") ;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO `listOfRides` (`address`, `time`)
 VALUES 
($address, $time)") ;
```